# Find out who overrides a class in IE Developer Tools

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, developer-tools, ie-developer-tools, ie11-developer-tools

I'm using IE developer toolbar to analyze the DOM. My question is: when you check a certain element, let's say a paragraph, and that paragraph has a class that will set its `background-color`, but for some reason that class is overridden by another class or whatever, the class with that specific rule is strike through. How can I find out what class or parent element overrides it?

Example:

[image]

How can I find out whom overrides this `background-color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in `Computed`—`background-color` (need to expand it) in **IE 11 Developer Tools**:
[image: IE 11 Developer Tools]

Or try to search it this way in **Chrome DevTools**:
[image: Chrome DevTools]

Answer (score 2):

There's an established order of what overrides what. This is determined by the level of **Specificity**. There are four levels: **element, class, id, and inline** (from least priority to highest priority).

There's also the **!important** rule that can supercede the natural order. If there are multiple "!important", then the last one will *win*.

For more information:
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/